# Homestead virtualbox error, the host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Iam trying to use homestead laravel, seems some issue that am feeling strange.

```
root@seetha-H81M-S:/home# homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
```

homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/Code
  to: /home/Homestead

sites:
- map: nal.app
  to: /home/seetha/Homestead/nal/public
```

There is a folder named Homestead in /home/Homestead , still seems not working.
I have find similar questions in stack-overflow but nothing seems working for me.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

**OS Ubuntu 14.04**

Comment: Do you have `~/Code` folder on your (host) machine?

Comment: yes i have no it is not there , am trying to make one now, thanks for your suggestion @Alik

Comment: what OS are you using ? windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux ,Ubuntu 14.04
Got an error after creating Code folder in root

default: /vagrant => /root/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant

Comment: I think its still folder mapping issue. please what is the path to Code folder in your host system(Ubuntu). Change `/home/Homestead` to `/home/vagrant/Code`

Comment: hi, have you resolved this issue?

Comment: in no way i found the solution, so i reinstalled the OS and dropped the homestead , instead of that i have installed all packages separately and working fine now.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and fixed it by `bash init.sh`

Run the `bash init.sh` command from the Homestead directory to create the Homestead.yaml configuration file. The Homestead.yaml file will be placed in the ~/.homestead hidden directory.

**If you are changing Homestead.yaml again, you have to re-run `bash init.sh` again. It will ask for overwrite, say yes.**

Answer (score 2):

You have this issue when your folders are not properly mapped.

This is how to map your folders in vagrant `Homestead.yaml`

```
folders:
- map: ~/Code    
  to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

`~/Code` means `/home/yourUsername/Code` must exist in your host computer. 
The code folder will house all your Laravel apps.

Example you could have the following apps in `Code` folder which are on your **host**

`/home/vagrant/Code/laravelapp`

`/home/vagrant/Code/laravelapp2`

Homestead.yaml may now look like this

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /wamp/www   
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravelapp/public
    - map: laravel.dev2
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravelapp2/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
```